# Loop statements executing for every value rather than specific value supplied

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to execute a program which o/p's different values based on condition. But it's getting inside every loop rather than the one it's specified for. And print multiple statements of all. Here's the code:

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday = bool):
for speed in range(86, 91):
    if is_birthday: True ,print("Big ticket")
for speed in range(66, 86):
    if is_birthday: True, print("Small ticket")
if speed < 66:
    if is_birthday: True, print("No ticket")
if speed > 81 and is_birthday == False:
    print("Big Ticket")
for speed in range(61, 81):
    if is_birthday: False , print("Small ticket")
if speed < 61:
    if is_birthday == False:
        print("No Ticket")
```

caught_speeding(61, True). 
Here I'm giving value 61 and is_birthday as 'True'. But my O/P is printing "Big Ticket"- 5 times and "Small Ticket"- 20 times. Where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to check if 61 <= speed < 81, etc, I found you have a problem in your code. `range(x, y)` returns a list, like so: `[61, 62, 63, 64, ... , 80]`. So, by writing a `for speed in range(x, y):` you **iterate** over every item to whom you assign the name **speed** in the list **range(x, y).** This means that the for-loop will be called 20 times, and thus will print "Small ticket" 20 times (the list range(61, 81) has 20 items).

If you want to check wether the given speed is **in** the range of values given by `range(61, 81)` you'll want to do one of the following:

```
if speed in range(61, 81):
    print("Small ticket")
```

This simply checks wether the list `range(61, 81)` has an item whose value is `speed`. You could also do:

```
for i in range(61, 81):
    if i == speed:
        print("Small ticket")
```

This gives you more control, but is less efficient and produces the same output.

The easiest solution though, would be doing the following:

```
if 61 <= speed < 81:
    print("Small ticket")
```

No need for a list.

Here's the complete code:

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):

    if is_birthday == True:

        if 86 <= speed < 91:
            print("Big ticket")

        if 66 <= speed < 86:
            print("Small ticket")

        if speed < 66:
            print("No ticket")

    if is_birthday == False:

        if speed >= 81:
            print("Big Ticket")

        if 61 <= speed < 81:
            print("Small ticket")

        if speed < 61:
            print("No Ticket")
```

Comment: Will take a note of that in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both conditions are true, is_birthday so you get "Big Ticket" && speed < 66, so you get "Small Ticket", you are actually doing all the for loops but not all of them are printing because of the condition inside, maybe an if/elsif controlling which loop do you want to use instead of using all the loops?

Oh and, look at the indentation on line 6

"If speed < 66:"

Comment: Will take a note of that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why using for? You should use e.g.

```
if speed in range(61,81)
```

without loops. You could also avoid multiple nesting
and use something like

```
if speed in range(61,81) and is_birthday: print('...')
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the second one, but didn't work. Thanks for the suggestions